# Calculate Date difference between two consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains datetime rows like below.

```
ID | DateTime

1  | 12:00
2  | 12:02
3  | 12:03
4  | 12:04
5  | 12:05
6  | 12:10
```

I want to identify those rows where there is a 'gap' of 5 minutes between rows (for example, row 5 and 6).

I know that we need to use `DATEDIFF`, but how can I only get those rows which are consecutive with each other?

Comment: Are the DateTime values always in order? (E.g. no 12:04 for ID = 7?)

Comment: How is "consecutive" defined? Is it by the `ID` column, by the `DateTime` column, or some other (set of) column(s)?

Comment: Consecutive is defined by date time

Comment: So the ID values doesn't matter? You just want to see if an older row, less than 5 minutes older exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`LAG`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), [**`LEAD`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) window functions for this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
  SELECT ID, [DateTime], 
         DATEDIFF(mi, LAG([DateTime]) OVER (ORDER BY ID), [DateTime]) AS prev_diff,
         DATEDIFF(mi, [DateTime], LEAD([DateTime]) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) AS next_diff
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE prev_diff >= 5 OR next_diff >= 5
```

**Output:**

```
ID
==
5
6
```

**Note:** The above query assumes that order is defined by `ID` field. You can easily substitute this field with any other field that specifies order in your table.

Comment: Looks like they actually want order by datetime rather than Id but easy to change.

Comment: @MartinSmith Could you provide the same solution for the SQLite database?

Comment: @pradipsutariya - (1) this is not my answer (2) If you have a new question [ask it as a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) not to random people in the comments of other questions

Comment: @MartinSmith Parden me! I was supposed to ask Giorgos Betsos to provide the same solution for the SQLite database if he has.

Comment: @pradipsutariya - this is still not the correct route to ask questions. Use the "Ask question" function on the site. I'm sure that Giorgos isn't running an adhoc support channel in the comments here

Answer (score 0):

### update SS2012: Use LAG

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, T TIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'12:00')
,(2,'12:02')
,(3,'12:03')
,(4,'12:04')
,(5,'12:05')
,(6,'12:10');

WITH TimesWithDifferenceToPrevious AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,T
          ,LAG(T) OVER(ORDER BY T) AS prev
          ,DATEDIFF(MI,LAG(T) OVER(ORDER BY T),T) AS MinuteDiff
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM TimesWithDifferenceToPrevious
WHERE ABS(MinuteDiff) >=5
```

The result

```
6   12:10:00.0000000    12:05:00.0000000    5
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this (I'm not sure if it's really fast)

```
SELECT current.datetime  AS current_datetime,
       previous.datetime AS previous_datetime,
       DATEDIFF(minute, previous.datetime, current.datetime) AS gap
FROM   my_table current
JOIN   my_table previous
  ON   previous.datetime < current.datetime
 AND   NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   my_table others
                   WHERE  others.datetime < current.datetime
                     AND  others.datetime > previous.datetime);
```